# How to run .out file in csh script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, csh

Is there any way to run `.out` file by Csh or any other shell script?
I want to run those files by one command.

It is okay to change script type, or use any different way. Please tell me the way to run ".out" file.

Code:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

sh ./update

if($# > 1) then
echo "Too many args."
exit
endif

if($# == 1) then

sh fo.out $1 text
sh fo.out $1 text

endif

./RUN.sh
```

Error:

```
fo.out: fo.out: cannot execute binary file
fo.out: fo.out: cannot execute binary file
```

1. I want to run "update", "fo.out", "Run.sh" by one command.
2. If I have don't have an argument, "fo.out" should not be executed.
3. My OS is Linux.

Comment: As an aside, most of us abandoned Csh in favor of saner shells 30+ years ago when Bourne-compatible shells with similar interactive features became available. See e.g. https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt for an overview of its problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state the file format of `fo.out`, but the shell error indicates it's a binary file. Run `file fo.out` on the command line to confirm what type of file it is, eg:

```bash
$ file fo.out      
fo.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Assuming it reports an executable file like this one, then you should be able to just run it in your script *without* the `sh` interpreter, ie:

```
./fo.out $1 text
```